# Wordpress booking form using Gravity forms

Tags: gravity

I created custom custom post types and fields using Toolset. I have aprox. 500 items and my goal is to create a booking form using Gravity forms and embedd this form using function call. Some fields in the Gravity forms need to be populated from some custom fields. Also I need prices calculation (basic price+addon+addon+addon). At the end I need to integrate payment processor. Please, I need developer recommendation or some hint how to do that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I cover almost all of these topics here:

http://wpsessions.com/sessions/gravity-forms-out-of-the-box/

Populating from custom fields:

https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/using-dynamic-population/

Comment: Hello David, thank you for answer. I've just bought lesson. How can I contact you for custom work? Is it possible?

Comment: Depends on the project. You can contact me here: http://ounceoftalent.com/contact/